# Alfresco Activiti - How to update a process definition in production/QA

Tags: alfresco, activiti

Is there a way to import a new version of a process definition in Activiti?

I have modified its definition in my development environment and now I need to update QA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add your process definition to an App, you can then export the App from one environment to the other.

All its process definitions, forms, stencils, etc... will be exported and re-imported in the new environment.

Be careful that, you have to execute the import being on the "details view" of the App otherwise it will create a new App and new process definitions!